# while loop, while a is not in the interval [a,b] run

Tags: python

Im setting up a while loop which should run until my value zero is equal to 0(or a very small interval near zero).
how is this written i python?

```
while (zero != 0 +/- k):

    if zero > 0:
        gamma = gamma+zero/100
    if zero < 0:
        gamma = gamma-zero/100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) `abs` (absolute value):

```
while abs(zero) > k:
    gamma = gamma + abs(zero)/100
```

You don't need your `if` checks then.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a funny beast here, you can write [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in the "mathematical way":

```
while -k < zero < k:
  ...
```